# Cómo arreglar el Error 08001 al conectar sql server 2019 con Python v3

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x

Ya intente muchas soluciones a errores similares sobre el controlador de sql server pero no me han funcionado. Acabo de ver una posible solución pero no se realizarla, consiste en entrar al SQL Server Configuration Manager, y habilitar los valores de "named pipes" en los protocolos del cliente. No se funcione, en resumidas cuentas lo que yo quiero es conectar python a sql server.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  import pyodbc
    DireccionServidor = '127.0.0.1'
    NombreBD = 'USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS'
    NombreUsuario = 'user'
    Contrasena = ''
    try:
        conexion = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                            DireccionServidor + ';DATABASE=' + NombreBD + ';UID=' + NombreUsuario + '; PWD=' + Contrasena)
        print("conexion exitosa")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ocurrió un error al conectar a SQL Server", e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que te estás tratando de conectar a tu instancia `USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS` usando la dirección loopback sin el puerto asignado a esa instancia. Lo ideal sería que uses el nombre de la instancia para conectarte y uses el nombre correcto de la base de datos (PIAS).

```
  import pyodbc
    DireccionServidor = 'USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS'
    NombreBD = 'PIAS'
    NombreUsuario = 'user'
    Contrasena = ''
    try:
        conexion = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                            DireccionServidor + ';DATABASE=' + NombreBD + ';UID=' + NombreUsuario + '; PWD=' + Contrasena)
        print("conexion exitosa")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ocurrió un error al conectar a SQL Server", e)
```